# IIS 7.5 URL rewriting not working

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, isapi, isapi-rewrite

Today I have set up a new site with ColdFusion 10 and IIS . My project uses URL rewriting , I have installed "urlrewrite2.exe" . After that I have imported 'httpd.conf' file given by the client to the site .

When I am browsing my site , the homepage is opening but on clicking on any link it throws error .[image]

Please help how can I fix this issue ? and why it is searching 'jakarta\isapi_redirect.dll'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a virtual directory named 'jakarta' and point it to `{ColdFusion Root}/config/wsconfig/1`